# What's the difference between "restart X" and "/etc/init.d/X restart"?

Tags: restart

I normally use this command to restart my daemons(e.g. vsftpd):

```
$sudo /etc/init.d/vsftpd restart
```

Early today I noticed it said that I can try restart(8) utility. I did:

```
$sudo restart vsftpd
```

It worked. But when I tried to restart my apache2:

```
$sudo restart apache2
> restart: Unknown job: apache2
```

Why are they different? Of course I can restart apache2 by /etc/init.d/apache2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The commands `start`, `stop`, `restart`, etc., are links for `initctl`, and only work for upstart jobs.

Calling directly the script in `/etc/init.d/` will give a warning for upstart jobs, for which the use of the script is allowed for convenience, through a wrapper symlinked common script.

Calling the `service` command always works, both for upstart jobs and for traditional sysv init scripts, so it is the preferred way.

Comment: And `apache2` happens to be a script that is not converted (yet?) to an Upstart job. `sudo start x` tries to load `/etc/init/x.conf`.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use service:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: @Lekensteyn: It is not the same (at least on 10.10), as restart will only refer to `initctl`, but `service` is more general and can be used both for *upstart* and *System V init*.

Comment: @arrange: confirmed in the source; it first checks for an upstart script in `/etc/init/apache2.conf` and if that cannot be executed, `/etc/init.d/apache2` is tried. The manual page does not include that though.